# Suitescript 2.0 Create Discount Item with % rate

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm tried to create a discount item with suitescript 2.0, but I get the following error:

"message": "You have entered an Invalid Field Value 70.0% for the following field: rate"

```
                    fieldId: 'rate',
                    value: (rate_discount.toFixed(1))+'&#37;'
                });
```

On Netsuite UI, I can add % to Rate field, and I need it to item can be rate by percent.

How can I create this item type with % rate?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `setText`.

```
var discountItem = record.create({type: record.Type.DISCOUNT_ITEM, isDynamic:true});
discountItem.setValue({fieldId:'itemid', value:'testDiscountItem'});
discountItem.setText({fieldId:'rate',text:'8.5%'});
discountItem.save();
```